# Partially evaluating right-handed operator sections

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc

I have a function `(*~)`. Most of the cost of evaluating `x *~ y` comes from inspecting the second argument, roughly along these lines:

```
(*~) :: a -> b d -> c d a
x *~ y = case y' of
           Bar -> cheapFunction y' x
           Baz -> cheapFunction2 y' x
           Quux -> cheapFunction3 y' x
  where
    y' = expensive y
```

Is there some way to convince GHC to partially evaluate operator sections like `(*~ y)`?

I tried rewriting it like:

```
(*~) = flip go
  where
    go y = let y' = expensive y
            in case y' of
                 Bar -> cheapFunction y'
                 Baz -> cheapFunction2 y'
                 Quux -> cheapFunction3 y'
```

but it didn't seem to help. I think this might be because `flip` requires all it's arguments before it does the flipping?

One way would just be to flip the operator itself, but it reads much more naturally when the expensive operand is on the right hand side, because it lines up with an existing notation.

Can a properly crafted `{-# RULE #-}` bail me out here? If so, what should it say? (I'm unclear on how far the sectioning syntax will have been desugared before rules look for matches, among other things.)

Comment: I'm not sure what partial evaluation would buy you. `y'` will already be shared. Do you want memoization? You'll need to add memoization yourself. What sort of rule would you want to write?

Comment: What happens if you use a custom `flip`? `flip' f x = \ y -> inline f y x`

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Will `y'` already be shared? If so then my understanding is pretty broken and I would love to accept an answer explaining how. If I do `fmap (*~ y) someLongList` won't it be recomputed each time?

Comment: I was referring to `y'` within the definition of `(*~)`, but I see what sort of sharing you want now and I think it depends on exactly how GHC desugars sections in a non-obvious way, so I don't know whether it will or not. You could always try to read the core and find out.

Comment: do I understand you correctly in that `seq y $ fmap (*~ y) someLongList` would not be satisfactory because you want the 2nd arg of the operator to _always_ be strict regardless of where the operator is invoked? and the problem is that it's not the 1st argument so currying doesn't help? how about switching the arg order and renaming to `~*`?

Comment: @ErikAllik I believe the issue is that it is not `y` which must be shared but the result of some intermediate computation performed *on* `y` by `(*~)`.

Comment: It's both of those issues. Splitting the intermediate out would help but would expose users to that currently-hidden and fairly strange implementation detail. I could flip it around and the currying would fix my issue, but it would make the resulting client code read in a very unnatural way.

Comment: @DougMcClean: by any chance, could you shed a bit more light into what your actual `*~` is doing? you've only provided pseudocode.

Comment: Sure, good question. The left operand is a numerical value and the right operand is a unit. The result is a quantity tagged with the same dimension as the unit had. The expensive (not in absolute terms, but relatively) part is combining all the units on the right hand side, extracting the numerical value, checking if it is exactly 1, and determining if we can get away with `coerce`. But now that I read Nikita Volkov's comment, I am finding a way. Because the unit combination part should be shared anyway (trying to determine a test to verify that), and I can make a function...

Comment: ...that logically is equivalent to `fmap (*~ u)` that only does the check in that case. That's actually even better, because then you aren't doing it in the case when you are only converting a single value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To trigger such an optimization you need to make sure that your function gets inlined. Place the `{-# INLINE (*~) #-}` pragma before the declaration of the `(*~)` function. I can't guarantee you that it'll solve your problem, but it's the only way I see it being approached. I'd examine the generated Core code with a tool like ["ghc-core"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core) afterwards to make sure.

However, your problem actually is just an indication of improper code composition. Your function is doing multiple unrelated things. `expensive y` should simply be factored out of it, then your problem will be erased as such. I.e., the usage pattern should be `x *~ expensive y` instead of `x *~ y`.

Comment: This is a good point and would solve the problem. But the result type of `expensive` is currently a hidden implementation detail because it is really of no interest to users of the library that exposes `(*~)`.

Comment: Actually, it would not be a hidden implementation detail in your case either, you'd just be exposing it differently. You'd also be obfuscating your intent and hiding this from the type system, and hence would have to otherwise inform the user of how your special function is supposed to be used. This wouldn't possibly be good from the usability standpoint. And, again, it'd go against separation of concerns. You have a list of indications of your approach being incorrect already, so better think twice.